# Jmeter : Wants to capture random tokens in frequent intervals of time

Tags: jmeter, token

I am testing a web application in Jmeter.
The application generates a random token and stores the token in coherence cache on the server-side(Expires in every 15 mins) every time we hit the random token request and pass the generated token in request headers of subsequent requests.
In subsequent requests, when we do submit, it validates token from request headers with token stored in the cache on the server-side. If it matches, the request will pass else fail.
How to handle this scenario in Jmeter.

The Big challenge here is we have enabled duplicate sessions due to challenges in the creation of user ids.
So the token has to get only once per user ID and pass the same token for all the duplicate sessions of the same user ID in all the requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't re-use the credentials, so each JMeter Thread (virtual user) would represent only one real user, you can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for parameterization of the credentials.
2. When the token is generated it is passed to the browser somehow, either in response body or in [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). So you should be able to extract it using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. For the subsequent requests add the relevant header via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and use the value from step 2 as the header value.